# write php page for every record on the database

Tags: php, loops

I am just learning PHP by working on a simple project of employees. I want to learn how to make a  php page for every record in the database. I have use while loop to create links in a  page to  every employee page. But I cant possibly manually create pages of every employee.
i read this thread: [How do I create file on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133999/how-do-i-create-file-on-server)

I want to run a loop function , inside there will be a layout  of  where every detail should be, like name here, id here, etc. and the function should loop for every record in the database, writing php files. And it should be saved as employeename.php, whatever the name may be. How is it possible?

Comment: Your loop + [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). I don't think a lot of PHP files is what you want. You can achieve the same result with some URL rewriting and a single PHP file that accepts a GET variable for the employee's name.

Comment: Do you mean literally create file .php for every employee ? Because it's possible to create one dynamic page that displays specific employee information by just passing the id

Comment: why you want save file for each user? make 1 file and use parameter? for example `employeename.php?empid=1`, if you want save you must use `file_put_contents` in you `while` loop

Comment: i thought of doing so but i thought that it would load slow,because for every link clicked there would be a lot of processing.. Am i wrong? if yes, how do i use the parameters?

Comment: There would be a slight performance impact but in your case it would still be smarter to use `$_GET` variables. Any variable in the query string you enter at the end of the URL is saved in a `$_GET` variable in PHP. For example, `page.php?foo=bar&abc=def` can be accessible in PHP using `$_GET['foo']` (which will return `bar`) and `$_GET['abc']` (which will return `def`).

Comment: @shrmn taher than putting all the variables in the link, its also possible that i just put the primary key of the record there and then in the page just fetch the infos from the record, by selecting the record using $_get, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single PHP file, using a get variable. 
for example:

URL: example.com/employees/?employee=Jhon_Doe

Code:

```
$employee = $_GET["employee"];
```

Finally, you use that name to recognize your particular employees record, and display their information.

As such:

```
<h1><?php echo $employeeData["name"]?></h1>
```

Note, the following advice, is advanced and may be to difficult for a beginner, I added it just for interest's sake.
If you would like to have clean urls(no ? marks) so it is not obvious that your using a single file, you can use rewrite rules:

add this to your .htacces file, which goes in the root directory of your server.

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/employees/([.]+)/$ /employees/?employee=$1

Comment: That IS difficult to understand.. Here are my doubts:  1- i have seen the htaccess file in filezilla, but how do i open it? in notepad.          2- what part of that rewrite string can i change acc. to my will?

Comment: to open your .htaccess, right click and hit open with. choose note pad. further more, I wrote the rewrite string so that any string of letters or numbers would work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating many PHP files, you'll likely want to have a single PHP script that can read the [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) global, and loads employee data conditionally based on the script argument. Here's some pseudo-code:

```php
   /* employee.php */
    switch($_GET['e']) {
        case 'john-smith':
            $info = getInfoFromDatabase('John Smith');
            break;
        case 'jane-doe':
            $info = getInfoFromDatabase('Jane Doe');
            break;
        /* ... etc ... */
    }

    displayInfo($info);
```

As you can see, this fictional file will load John Smith's information when accessed at `employee.php?e=john-smith` and Jane Doe's info at `employee.php?e=jane-doe` and so on. You can then have as many employee records in the database as you want and you never have to change anything.

Comment: thanks for that, but i dont have a database for every employee, they are just records. so can i do something like select * from table where id=$_GET['E'] ? then then, wherever i want the deatils to display, get using fetch_array?

Comment: @SauravChaudhary Do you have a database OF employees? Your post states that "I want to learn how to make a php page for every record **in the database**."

Comment: Well, `getInfoFromDatabase` can be anything, really. It's just meant to represent Whatever method you have of getting the employee's information.

Comment: @SauravChaudhary Yes you can. You need to sanitize the input for security though. An example query (non-secure) could be `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TblEmployees WHERE name = '".$_GET['e']."'");`

Comment: @shrmn how can i make it secure. All i have read in w3schools(thats where i learned php) is the use of htmlspecialchars and stuff. Will that do or anything else may also be necessary?

Comment: @shrmn the fetch array method will work with loops right, since i know there will only beone loop. You see, in w3schools they have used only loops to display stuff from the database? is there any alternative to loops for displaying data?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is not addressing your question directly, but when reading your question and the comments that followed I would like to give you *an answer that I wish I got when I was a PHP-beginner*:

**Learn PHP by using a framework**, such as [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/tour/)

Pros starting with a framework

1. You get a good structure and learning PHP- best practices
2. You will have many examples - and I found it easy to learn from examples.

Cons

1. The learning curve is a lot steeper. It took me a few intensive days to get things to work, but in the end it was worth it.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will definitely try it out. Right now for learning with examples, I use wamp. it wont interfere with its settings right?    I wish I could vote up your answer but even that requires 15 reputations!

Comment: No, Yii Framework would only build on top of the "P" in WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP), an perhaps i requires Apache as well.